# Trying to save the Encrypted Phone_Office value in the accounts module of Sugar CRM but the same is not getting reflected in the database?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Encrypted the Phone_Office value entered in the UI before Saving and the encrypted value is passed to the Phone_Office .But the value is not getting saved in the database.I have made changes in the following file :-**Modules/Accounts/AccountsFormBase.PHP** in this i added my code under the following function :-
    **function handleSave($prefix,$redirect=true, $useRequired=false)**{
//Other Code written for Accounts module lies here //Below is the code snippet added by me.

```
$text = $_POST['phone_office'];

$PhNum = $_POST['phone_office'];

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open ( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '' );

$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ( $cipher );

$key = '12345678901234561234567890123456'; 

$iv = '9532654BD781547023AB4FA7723F2FCD';
```

// Encrypt

```
if (mcrypt_generic_init ( $cipher, $key, $iv ) != - 1) {
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic ( $cipher, $text );
mcrypt_generic_deinit ( $cipher );
}
// Decrypt

if (mcrypt_generic_init ( $cipher, $key, $iv ) != - 1) {
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic ( $cipher, $encrypted );
mcrypt_generic_deinit ( $cipher );
}

$txtE = bin2hex ( $encrypted );

$phone_office = $txtE;

if(!$focus->ACLAccess('Save')){
    ACLController::displayNoAccess(true);
    sugar_cleanup(true);
}

$focus->save($check_notify);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct variable for the phone number:

```
$focus->phone_office = $txtE;
```

You currently assign the value to a new variable and when you save the focus the new variable is not used.